# Rate limiting of request using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a requirement to trigger 100 requests for min for a duration of 10 mins.

Can i use below configuration.
Under Thread Group
Number of Threads: 1000 (100 * 10 mins)
Rampup: 600 (10 mins * 60)
Number of iterations: 1
This will execute 1000 request for a duration of 10 mins. Can you please let know if this a right/best approach ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want evenly distributed requests you should go for one of the following:

1. [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer):

   [image]
2. [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer):

   [image]
3. [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin):

   [image]

In all cases the number of threads should be **sufficient** in order to reach and maintain the target throughput and it depends on your application under test response time. In case of Throughput Shaping Timer you can connect it with [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) so JMeter would be able to kick off extra threads if current amount is not enough.